# How do I evaluate a string key in Groovy so that it outputs a value?

Tags: gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

we're defining a key/value property in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties like so:

**~/.gradle/gradle.properties**:

```
FOO=BAR
```

If we do:

```
println "$FOO" // prints BAR
```

it works, but if we try to make it a function that looks like this:

```
def getEnvValueForKey = { keyStr ->
    return "$keyStr"
}
```

`getEnvValueForKey("FOO")` returns `FOO` instead of `BAR`

How do we make that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getEnvValueForKey(key)` function returns always a GString representation of a variable passed as a parameter. The expression `"$keyStr"` is actually an alternative for `"" + keyStr.toString()`. The same thing happens when you call `"$FOO"` == `"" + FOO.toString()`.

If you want to get a property defined in `gradle.properties` file you can redefine your function to something like this:

```
def getEnvValueForKey = { keyStr ->
  return this.getProperties().getOrDefault(keyStr, null)
}
```

Calling `getEnvValueForKey("FOO")` in this case evaluates to

```
this.getProperties().getOrDefault("FOO", null)
```

If in current scope variable `FOO` exists it will return its value and `null` otherwise.

Keep in mind that `this.getProperties()` returns a map of all properties/variables defined in current scope of Gradle task being executed.